# Qual é a diferença entre o método PUT e o PATCH?

Tags: http, http-métodos

Alguns ensinam que para atualizar utiliza o `PUT` e outros ensinam utilizando o `PATCH`.

Então, afinal, qual é a diferença entre o método PUT e o PATCH?

Quando devo usar um e outro?

Comment: Acredito que a pergunta **link**ada já responda sua duvida =)

Comment: Não creio ser duplicata, a resposta na pergunta linkada é bastante tem respostas vagas (claro que explicar um método por um seria exagero nela), pela falta de detalhes lá acho totalmente válido formular uma pergunta sobre o *"assunto especifico"*, a comunidade irá se beneficiar se as respostas tiverem exemplos da estrutura do "Verbo" e explicação de como ocorre o processo em ambas. ;)

Comment: @LINQ
Creio que a pergunta não seja duplicada. A pergunta linkada pergunta de todos os métodos e não traz a diferença entre o PUT e PATCH. E também não traz exemplos de como usar.

Comment: @Newtech Tudo bem. pra isso que serve o "possível". Mas seguinte: a pergunta linkada mostra sim as diferenças entre um e outro, ela explica o que é um e o que é o outro, nisso dá pra ver as diferenças. Eu não entendi a questão dos exemplos, você quer saber em qual momento usar um ou outro?

Comment: Em alguns lugares de web semântica eu vi falando para usar apenas os métodos **GET**, **DELETE**, **POST** e **PUT**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Em poucas palavras, os métodos HTTP `PUT` e `PATCH` são usados para indicar um requisição de alteração de dados.

Geralmente, ao usar-se o `PUT`, fica legível que a alteração do dado será com referência a entidade completa.

Exemplo: `(/usuario/1234)` :

Resultado: `{'id': 1234, 'name': 'Joao', 'idade': 25, 'documento': '123.321.12-X'}`

O `PATCH` é usado para atualização parcial, quando você não quer mandar o payload completo.

Exemplo: `(/usuario/1234)` :

Resultado: `{'name': 'João'}`

Referências:

- [RFC5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789)
- [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-55)

Comment: Falta o detalhe do PUT: the origin server can create the resource with that URI.