# GET, POST ou PUT, qual usar para emissão de uma nota fiscal?

Tags: api, http, http-request

Qual devo usar quando a intenção não é visualizar, salvar e nem atualizar os dados?

Estou criando uma API que faz a emissão de nota fiscal eletronica, fiz o CRUD completo para as informações das notas, mas agora preciso criar um recurso que transmite o XML para a sefaz, tipo:

```
http://localhost/api/nfes/10/transmite
```

pensei em usar PUT ou PATCH, pois a requisição terminará atualizando o status da NFe de "Pendente" para "Autorizada" no banco de dados, só que não terá nenhum corpo na requisição... o que acham?

Comment: retorna alguma coisa?

Comment: só um JSON com as respostas da sefaz como "nota fiscal autorizada" ou "rejeitada - informar ie do destinatário" etc

Comment: Como você disse que "terminará atualizando o status da NFe no banco de dados", poderia excluir o GET das suas opções

Comment: eu tinha pensado no GET só por que não está sendo enviado nenhum dado na requisição, apenas o ID da nfe pela URI...

Comment: Todas as emissões serão manuais? Por quê não emitir logo que a nota é gerada?

Comment: Você pode definir outro recurso para isso, algo como `/api/emissao/<id>` e fazer um POST para uma nova emissão. Além disso, você pode criar uma tabela no banco para gerenciar as emissões e manter um histórico de tentativas - útil para quando dá erro na emissão.

Comment: Por que as vezes o usuário insere alguma informação incorreta e quer corrigor ou quer visualizar o DANFE PRÉVIA antes de transmitir... quase sempre existe algumas burocracias entre o preenchimento e a transmissão, por isso...

Comment: Sobre PUT vs PATCH, olha aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/217894/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-m%C3%A9todo-put-e-o-patch

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, achei sensacional sua ideia, vou implementar o /api/emissao

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Determinar qual método utilizar em cada situação sempre é uma discussão delicada. A implementação deve ser conforme as necessidades e limitações do projeto.

Inclusive os métodos, mesmo previstos em uma especificação, [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3), podem variar conforme a aplicação. Pode existir uma API que utiliza o método GET para gerar um novo registro, POST para excluir, etc. Porém, obviamente, imagina a confusão que seria documentar e utilizar essa API? Quanto menos comportamentos estranhos sua aplicação possuir, mais fácil será de utilizá-la.

Sem saber os detalhes do seu projeto, somente com o que foi detalhado na pergunta, vejo duas possíveis soluções:

1. Utilizar o método PATCH;
2. Criar um recurso próprio;

Mas cada um com suas peculiaridades:

Ao utilizar o método PATCH para emitir a nota fiscal, certifique-se de nunca utilizar o mesmo método para mais nada; caso contrário encontrará problemas. O método PATCH costuma-se ser utilizado para atualizações parciais de um recurso. Bem como disse, a emissão da nota alteraria apenas o status da nota e, de certa forma, faria sentido fazer a emissão no PATCH. Mas e se você precisar alterar outros campos da nota fiscal? Uma forma seria você fazer a emissão da nota somente quando o status da mesma é alterada de um valor qualquer para emitida - e, por favor, use transações aqui. Assim, se fosse para alterar qualquer outro campo, tal como o NCM de um produto, caso necessário, você poderia fazê-lo sem se preocupar se a nota seria emitida ou não.

Mas eu vejo um possível problema com esta abordagem: e se, por algum motivo, uma nota fiscal for emitida manualmente e você deseja apenas alterar o status para emitida? Se definir o status para emitida, o seu sistema tentará emití-la de novo - você pode até tratar o retorno de duplicidade da nota e ignorar o erro, mas é um comportamento estranho para um sistema tentar emitir uma nota já emitida. Alguém de fora, que não participou do projeto do sistema, ao tentar atualizar o status não esperaria que a nota fosse emitida - ela quer alterar parcialmente o recurso, apenas, não emití-la.

Neste caso, eu sugeriria a segunda abordagem: criar um recurso próprio apenas para a emissão da nota fiscal:

```
POST /api/emissoes/ HTTP/1.1

id=1
```

Desta forma, você poderia utilizar o método POST para criar uma nova emissão e, assim, já deixa em aberto para possíveis/prováveis implementações futuras de um histórico de emissões. Você pode criar uma tabela no banco de dados onde você armazena a nota fiscal emitida e o retorno obtido do SEFAZ. Com o método GET, você pode obter o retorno de uma determinada emissão ou uma lista de várias emissões a fim de gerar relatórios.

Sem contar que você poderia utilizar o método PATCH para emitir cartas de correção e DELETE para cancelamento de notas, por exemplo.

Mas, ressaltando, que você, que é responsável pelo projeto, que conhece todos os requisitos e limitações, que deverá saber o que é melhor. No [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45948133#45948133), por exemplo, questionaram-me se em um *endpoint* que só aceita GET/POST/PUT, como poderia ser feito uma atualização parcial que seria feita no PATCH. Como possivelmente faria menos sentido criar um *endpoint* somente para fazer a atualização parcial do recurso, sugeri a utilização do próprio PUT, com um parâmetro adicional indicando se a atualização deverá ser parcial ou não. Nem sempre é a melhor solução, mas para o problema apresentado, parece ser.

E não custa lembrar que existem muitas aplicações que sobrevivem apenas com GET/POST, pois o formulário do HTML é incapaz de enviar outro tipo de requisição.

> **Nota:** aliás, se for uma API de uso interno da empresa, nada te impede de criar métodos HTTP personalizados - desde que o ambiente esteja devidamente configurado. Por exemplo, poderia criar um método chamado EMIT e fazer a requisição: `EMIT /nota-fiscal/1 HTTP/1.1`. Só não é recomendado utilizar isso em APIs públicas, pois nem todos os clientes podem suportar métodos personalizados.

Comment: Sensacional, obrigado pela explicação!

Answer (score 1):

Você diz:

> Qual devo usar quando a intenção não é visualizar, salvar e nem atualizar os dados?

E depois no fim da pergunta diz:

> pois a requisição terminará atualizando o status da NFe de "Pendente" para "Autorizada" no banco de dados

Tendo isso em vista, a requisição irá atualizar o status da nota, se entendermos o que o Maniero respondeu [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/92882/77723), o método ideal para você é `PUT`.

> Ou seja, o PUT deveria ser usado em situações mais específicas onde se quer enviar uma informação e não fazer mais nada além de armazená-la de alguma forma.

Uma API que utiliza o PUT para atualização de dados é a CIELO, se você consultar [esse método](https://developercielo.github.io/manual/cielo-ecommerce#modificando-recorr%C3%AAncias), ele serve de forma parecida com o que você está querendo fazer e utiliza `PUT` também.

Comment: Neste caso, então, o ideal seria o PATCH, pois o PUT, normalmente, espera o objeto completo e sobrescreve o banco. O PATCH apenas atualiza os dados recebidos: atualização parcial.

Comment: sim, também pensei no PATCH, mas creio que a resposta para a minha pergunta já foi respondida via comentário pelo @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: @JeffersonCarlosBD de boa, vou apagar minha resposta e estudar os comentários assim ja adiciono um pontinho no conhecimento hehe... de qualquer forma depois posta a solução e o porque dela como ressposta para a pergunta não ficar vazia caso o AndersonCarlosWoss não coloque a dele.

Comment: não precisa apagar sua resposta, ela pode ser a solução de outra pessoa, meu caso é bem especifico, mas a pergunta é bem genérica...